# Finding a date between two date columns in Azure Python

Tags: python, datetime, azure-machine-learning-service, strptime, strftime

I'm trying to find all dates in one column that fall between the dates in 2 other columns, but I'm still getting results from outside of the limits. I suspect it may be an issue with strftime, and I should be using strptime instead, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The data I have is something like this:

```
Prod_Date                 Date                      Lead_Date
08/02/1985 12:00:00 AM    08/02/1970 12:00:00 AM    08/02/1988 12:00:00 AM
08/02/1986 12:00:00 AM    08/02/1971 12:00:00 AM    08/02/2018 12:00:00 AM
08/02/1987 12:00:00 AM    08/02/1972 12:00:00 AM    08/02/1986 12:00:00 AM
08/02/1988 12:00:00 AM    08/02/1973 12:00:00 AM    08/02/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

I want to limit the dataframe to Prod_Date values that fall between the Date and Lead_Date columns. I don't get any errors with my code, but I'll get a lot of erroneous values that are either before the Date value, or after the Lead_Date value.

```html
# imports up here can be used to 
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<dataframe1>: a pandas.DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a pandas.DataFrame
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    # Convert strings to datetime
    dataframe1['Date'] = dataframe1.Date.apply(
        lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))

    dataframe1['Prod_Date'] = dataframe1.Prod_Date.apply(
        lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
 
    dataframe1['Lead_Date'] = dataframe1.Lead_Date.apply(
        lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
        
    # Keeping only the rows for production that are contained between the date and lead_date:
    dataframe1 = dataframe1[(dataframe1['Date'] < dataframe1['Prod_Date']) & (dataframe1['Prod_Date'] < dataframe1['Lead_Date'])]
```

Comment: I published an experiment [in the gallery](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Pandas-Dates) using your Python code. Does that look like it does what you need? I just added it to return `dataframe1` in the script.

Comment: It does work, which makes me think that the issue must be elsewhere in my data.